# Setting environment variables in virtualenv (Python, Windows)

Tags: python, windows, flask, pycharm, virtualenv

As the title suggests, I'm trying to use a environment variable in a config file for a Flask project (in windows 10).

I'm using a virtual env and this far i have tried to add `set "DATABASE_URL=sqlite:///models.db"` to /Scripts/activate.bat in the virtualenv folder. 
But it does not seem to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Flask does not automatically take configuration variables from environment variables. You have to set them manually like so:

```
app.config.from_envvar('YOURAPPLICATION_SETTINGS')
```

More info regarding configuration can be found [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/).

To set an environment variable in Windows, you should do as described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt):

```
setx DATABASE_URL=sqlite://something.something
```

Comment: This is the code for reading the config
`app.config.from_object('config.DevelopmentConfig')`

and in the config file:

`class DevelopmentConfig(BaseConfig)
   SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']`

This is the errormessage i get:

`config.py", 
line 7, in BaseConfig
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
  os.py",
 line 425, in __getitem__
    return self.data[key.upper()]
KeyError: 'DATABASE_URL'`

Comment: Yes, but from what i can see in the docs there is no information on how to set an environment variable in a virtualenv (windows)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that PyCharm does not activate the virtualenvironment when pressing the run button. It only uses the virtualenv python.exe.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I am trying to do the same thing using Pycharm on Windows.